# Magento Stress test

Tags: performance, magento2.2.3, testing, pagespeed

I've built a website using **Magento version 2.2.3**. Now, I want to stress test my website. I've heard that the **JMeter** is one of the best tools for testing the performance of the site.

So I used JMeter for stress testing. The attached image is the summary report of stress test for our website:

[image]

From this report, how to check whether my website is good enough when there is a huge load?

Please comment.

Answer (score 1):

Jmeter shows the reports in different formats with different values related to each specific request you hit. To understand what this report parameter stats you can get the details at : http://www.testingjournals.com/understand-summary-report-jmeter/ or you can also read the Jmeter user guide.

Once you understand the report parameters, you can compare those with your requirement and standards to understand the performance of your website.